# My PhD supervisor is starting a formal procedure to remove himself as my supervisor

Tags: phd, research-process

Does anyone have any experience with this? The coordinator of my program told me that he will schedule a meeting with my supervisor, the coordinator, and myself and that during that meeting they will come up with specific tasks which I need to complete. However, regardless of how "objective" those tasks are, my supervisor is not happy with me and I know that he will not let me 'pass' those meetings. He will do anything he can in his power to show the coordinator that I am not a good student. Has anyone gone through a procedure like this? Does the supervisor always kick the student out?

Comment: What is your plan to graduate if you were to *stay* with a supervisor who does not want to supervise you?

Comment: The headline doesn't match the question. Are you just assuming they are doing something formal or have you been told

Comment: @Buffy the coordinator ttold me that my supervisor wanted to schedule tthat tmeetting.

Comment: I'm not asking about the meeting, but it sounds like you may be making assumptions about the purpose. Also, this may be impossible to answer other than locally. Procedures differ everywhere. They may or may not have power over your student status.

Comment: I don't understand why you ask "does the supervisor always kick the student out?". As far as I know, if the supervisor gives up their role then the institution has a duty to provide another supervisor. It's not the same as when a supervisor wants to redirect the student to a Master degree for instance, i.e. the supervisor claims that the student is not able to succeed at all. Basically it's either the supervisor who is unable (or unwilling) to continue in their role, or it's the student. I would imagine that, in most institution, the procedure is different in these two scenarios.

Comment: @Erwan: As far as I can tell, at least de facto a department does NOT have a duty to provide a supervisor; the department can always dismiss the student from the program instead.  In all the PhD granting departments I have been a part of, part of the regulations say that the student must find a faculty member to be their supervisor by their n-th year (for some n) or be kicked out, and another part of the regulations say that, if a student's supervisor no longer wishes to work with them, the student must find another faculty member to be their supervisor within some period of time.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo interesting, this is very different from the institutions I've been (in Europe). Does this mean that a supervisor could potentially get rid of their student arbitrarily, without even motivating their decision?

Comment: @Erwan they probably could but it would be very rare if they would: this is a loose-loose situation, and it *is* embarrassing for everyone.  If something like this happened regularly the graduate chair would likely try to figure out what’s going on.

Comment: It sounds like *you* are not happy with your supervisor, in which case you should have changed supervisor as soon as possible.

Comment: @Erwan: Remember that, in the US, employers can usually fire their employees arbitrary without any motivation for their decision.  Unless there are contractual obligations that apply (and that covers around 10% of non-government workers), the only restriction is that the employer cannot be discriminating on the basis of race, religion, sex, age, veteran status, or a few other things I'm forgetting.

Comment: I had a friend whose supervisor gave red on their thesis defense but they got it with majority votes. Strange life...

Comment: Would you know the difference if, purely for example, your supervisor had recently found out he has terminal cancer and is shedding all his responsibilities?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo sure, but PhD students are also students. I'm a bit surprised that the institution doesn't have any responsibility in ensuring that a student can finish their degree if they didn't fail anything.

Comment: @Erwan The institution has a responsibility to ensure the student does not pass without reaching a reasonable standard.   They have a responsibility to create reasonable conditions for students - no unreasonable barriers. They have, however, no responsibility in ensuring the student can finish  - that's ultimately down to the student.  People do fail to finish what (at postgrad level) are intended to be hard achievements to earn.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Not really relevant since the question isn't about an employment situation.

Comment: @Erwan I expect most PhD programs have a clause along the lines of "to remain in the program students must continue to make satisfactory progress towards the degree"; if the supervisor believes a student is not making satisfactory progress, that **is** failing. There may be a safety net that requires others to assent to this designation to not put all the power in the hands of the supervisor, but a PhD is not like a bachelors degree: courses and grades don't matter, it's all about research.

Comment: @BryanKrause I agree with this, my initial point was precisely to make the distinction between the case where the student's progress is deemed insufficient and the case where the supervisor wants out for reasons unrelated to the student's level. I was told that in some institutions the supervisor can arbitrarily decide to end the PhD without motivating their decision, this is the part that surprises me. In my experience, if there's no evidence that the student is at fault then the institution must find a new supervisor. But apparently this is not the case everywhere.

Answer (score 39):

We don't know the details, of course, but in the end you do not have a *right* to be supervised by a specific professor. If a professor does not want to be your supervisor (any more), then there is relatively little you can objectively do.

There is a kind of "code of conduct" that professors see students they have accepted as advisees to graduation, simply because it (i) doesn't look very good on the department if someone just willy-nilly decides they don't want to do it any more, and (ii) because it creates a hassle for the department to then figure out what to do with the situation. As a consequence, it doesn't happen very often that a professor un-assigns themselves from being adviser. But it happens (and I have done it myself) if there are good reasons for it -- a typical one being that the student turns out to be on a trajectory where they have no chance to graduate with the degree they seek (and don't take the hint that it is best if they looked for a job elsewhere, outside grad school), or if there are substantial personal disagreements between student and faculty.

You do not say why your adviser wants to un-assign themselves. It is, also, strictly speaking not part of your question and so need not be answered. But I would strongly recommend to walk around the block a half dozen times and think hard why you got into this situation. Your question very much reads like "my adviser is unreasonable and wants to kick me out of the program". But experience shows that most advisers are not in fact unreasonable, and that there are good reasons why they do not want to advise a student any more; it would be good for you to consider what these reasons might be, and what needs to be done to address these. Completing the tasks required of you might be a good first step.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133537/discussion-on-answer-by-wolfgang-bangerth-my-phd-supervisor-is-starting-a-formal).

Comment: General remark: The comments under this question and answers by OP gave quite a bit of insight into the question. Unfortunately they were "moved to chat", but I suggest reading them before posting or judging answers.

Answer (score 6):

> The coordinator of my program told me that he will schedule a meeting with the 3 of us and that during that meeting they will come up with specific tasks which I need to complete.

You do not mention any formal process and it just sounds like a meeting to decide what tasks you should be doing.  I don't see an issue with this.  It may be as simple and non-threatening as it sounds.

*From comment...*

> My supervisor is young and new and my lab mate and I are the first students he sees.

So maybe your supervisor is finding this just as difficult and challenging as you are.  They will have a *lot* of things to do apart from supervise and may be finding it overwhelming.  You think you are being ignored (or something like that) but it may simply be that you are a task too much for your inexperienced supervisor.  It may be that issues outside of their control (and of which you know nothing) are making it much harder for them to deal with you than you understand.  Keep an open mind.

In comments you mention a lot of distrust between you and your supervisor.  That's unhealthy at best and self-destructive at worst.  It is not all clear that you even wrote an email explaining the issues from your point of view to your supervisor or their boss.  Don't assume verbal communications have any weight - they are often interpreted and/or remebered differently by the parties involved.

You have an *extremely* negative view of your supervisor at this point and, right or wrong (and we don't know), it really is not practical for you to continue with *your own viewpoint* so negative.  If you cannot adopt a more positive mental approach (and maybe you have good reasons - we don't know the reality) then you need to consider changing supervisor or even seeking an amicable parting of the ways from the institute and possibly reapplying elsewhere.

If you do find yourself with a new supervisor or seeking a new opportunity elsewhere the you need to start with a clean mental and emotional plate.